# How to add a linked field in a view from the DetailView class?

Tags: django

There are two models: *Document* - information about the document, *DocVersion* - text of the document in a certain edition. Linked via ForeignKey, as one document can have several texts with different revision dates.

```
class Document(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    doc_title = models.TextField(verbose_name="Name")

class DocVersion(models.Model):
    date_version = models.DateField(verbose_name="Version date")
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_start = models.DateField(verbose_name="Start date")
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name="Text")
```

View based on the DetailView class.

```
class DocumentDetailView(generic.DetailView):
model = Document

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(DocumentDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['text'] = '?????text??????'
    return context
```

How to fill *text* with data from the *text* field of the *DocVersion* model with the latest *date_start*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one `Document` can have multiple `DocVersion`, you need to speicfy which version you want. If it is the latest then:

```
class DocumentDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Document

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DocumentDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['text'] = context['object'].docversion_set.last().text
        return context
```

I am using [**`last()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#last) to get latest `DocVersion` object.

If you want all the text from all versions, then:

```
class DocumentDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Document

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DocumentDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['texts'] = context['object'].docversion_set.all().values_list('text')
        return context
```

Then you need to iterate through `texts` to render it in template:

```
{% for text in texts %}
   {{ text }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How how to change `context` to get data from a row in which field `date_start` is the most recent? `date_start = models.DateField`

Comment: you can send it via url querystring. for example: `/doc/1/?date_start=01/01/2020`, then you can get the value from `self.request.GET('date_start')`.

Comment: If add another model associated with the Document "one-to-one" (e.g. `DocType`). How can I get from two models at the same time?

Comment: First, get the max value for `date_start` with:
`res = context['object'].docversion_set.aggregate(this_date=Max('date_start'))`
`Max` is in `django.db.models`

Then, filter by that date in order to get required `DocVersion` instance.

Comment: @LlaveLuis that would be an overcomplicated solution. If you need the latest object by date, then simply use `context['object'].docversion_set.latest('date_start')`.

Comment: @АнтонЧеркашин if you want to add a one to one object, then simply try like: `context['one_to_one_object'] = context['object'].yourmodelname` where assuming `YourModelName` is the model where there is a reference to `Document` with One to One relation.